# React JS into Eclipse IDE

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React JS and trying to use in my front end design. Using Eclipse IDE,I would like to integrate React JS into my existing web application. Is it enough to add Jars associated with React into WEB-INF/lib and proceed?
Your help and time is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Another approach could be using something lightweight like VSCODE with create-react-app. Once you build the project you'll load it into your existing project as a singular widget.